# Why are copy and move constructors called together?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
     A(int) { cout << "int" << endl; }
     A(A&&) { cout << "move" << endl; }
     A(const A&) { cout << "copy" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> v
    {
        A(10), A(20), A(30)
    };

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
int
int
int
copy
copy
copy
```

`A(10)`, `A(20)` and `A(30)` are temporaries, right?

So why is the copy constructor called? Shouldn't the move constructor be called instead?

Passing `move(A(10))`, `move(A(20))`, `move(A(30))` instead, the output is:

```
int
move
int
move
int
move
copy
copy
copy
```

In this case either copy or move constructor is called.

What's happening?

Comment: You can't move from `initializer_list` elements. The additional `move` in your second example inhibits copy elision and so you get an additional move on top of the copy.

Comment: Good question; the answer is buried in here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: Inside a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list` in `std::vector`, those elements are no longer rvalue.

Comment: Additionally, if you were to call `v.push_back()` a few times, until the vector exceeded its capacity and had to reallocate, you would get a bunch of copies rather than moves. To prevent that you would need to mark your move constructor `noexcept`.

Comment: @ArneVogel: I'm torn. One one hand the "update" to that question is very similar to this one. On the other hand those answers are woefully incomplete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::vector` can be constructed from a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), and you are calling that constructor. The rules for initializer_list construction state that this constructor is aggressively preferred:

> A constructor is an *initializer-list* constructor if its first parameter is of type `std::initializer_list<E>`
>   or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list<E>` for some type `E`, and either there are
>   no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6). [ Note: Initializer-list
>   constructors are favored over other constructors in list-initialization <...>]

Also, because of the sort of weird implementation of an `initializer_list` as an array allocated under the hood, elements of the corresponding array that the `std::initializer_list<E>` refers to are forced to be copy initialized (which can be elided):

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation
>   allocated an array of `N` elements of type `E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list.
>   Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and
>   the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array

(Both references above from N3337 [dcl.init.list])

However, in your first example the copies can/are *elided* despite the name ([dcl.init]/14) so you don't see an extra copy construction (they can also be moved) You can thank your compiler for that, because *copy elision* is not required in C++11 (although it is in C++17).

See [class.copy] for more details ("When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
object...").

The final part is key:

[support.initlist] states that

> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`.

This means that the `std::vector` cannot take over the memory directly; it must be copied, this is where you ultimately see the copy constructions being called.

In the second example it is as Kerrek SB stated, you prevented the copy-elision I mentioned earlier and caused an additional overhead of a move.

Comment: Seems like a `vector(std::initializer_list&&)` would be useful :(

Answer (score 5):

> A(10), A(20), A(30) are temporaries, right?

Correct.

> So why the copy constructor is called? Shouldn't the move constructor be called instead?

Unfortunately, it is not possible to move from `std::initializer_list`, which is what this constructor of `std::vector` uses.

> Passing move(A(10)), move(A(20)), move(A(30)) instead
>
> In this case either copy or move constructor are called. What's happening?

Because the `std::move` conversion prevents copy-elision, and so the elements of the `std::initializer_list` are move constructed without elision. Then the constructor of vector copies from the list.